# Trying to search for needles in haystacks using dynamic queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please consider the following SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d4fc/3

I have 3 documents:

```
('id1', 'lorem ipsum dolor dog'),
('id2', 'the cat jumps over the lazy dog'),
('id3', 'i have no clue what to write');
```

I want to dynamically search these documents for needles:

```
('a', 'dog'),
('b', 'dolor'),
('c', 'write');
```

The results I need would be table `tmp_auditlog_results` looking like

```
doc   needle  string
---------------------------------------------
id1   dog     lorem ipsum dolor dog
id2   dog     the cat jumps over the lazy dog
id1   dolor   lorem ipsum dolor dog
id3   write   i have no clue what to write
```

I got confused by the dynamic query adding to the result table. Could you please have a look how I can get this result from the result I have now? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the 'a','b' and 'c' for?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT tmp_auditlog_results (doc,needle,string)
    SELECT doc, needles.needle, string 
    FROM  haystacks
    INNER JOIN needles ON haystacks.string like '%'+needles.needle+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any dynamic code. You can use `CHARINDEX`

```
INSERT INTO tmp_auditlog_results
SELECT S.docid, F.NEEDLE 
FROM tmp_auditlog_subselection AS S
CROSS JOIN tmp_auditlog_fields AS F
WHERE CHARINDEX(F.needle, S.haystack) != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the select statement:

```
select * from tmp_auditlog_fields;
```

with following statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'id' + CAST(A.id as VARCHAR(9999)) AS doc, needle,  B.haystack 
FROM tmp_auditlog_fields A
INNER JOIN tmp_auditlog_subselection B 
ON B.docid =  'id'+ CAST(A.id as VARCHAR(9999))
```

Comment: He can choose the id limit on his own it doesn't need to be max.

Comment: I've never seen IDs that long before ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from podiluska needed some renaming of column names. So i created this example starting from his query

Given these Tables

```
CREATE TABLE Haystacks (
  docid varchar(255),
  haystack varchar(255)
)
CREATE TABLE Needles (
  id int identity(1,1),
  fieldid varchar(255),
  needle varchar(255)
)
```

And these records

```
insert into Haystacks (docid, haystack) values
  ('id1', 'lorem ipsum dolor dog'),
  ('id2', 'the cat jumps over the lazy dog'),
  ('id3', 'i have no clue what to write');


insert into Needles (fieldid, needle) values
  ('a', 'dog'),
  ('b', 'dolor'),
  ('c', 'write');
```

This query

```
SELECT docid, needles.needle, haystack 
FROM Haystacks
INNER JOIN Needles ON Haystacks.haystack 
like '%'+Needles.needle+'%'
```

returns this result

[image: sqlfiddle result of query above]

See [this demo fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdf195/1) this matches the expected query result

```
    doc   needle  string
    ---------------------------------------------
    id1   dog     lorem ipsum dolor dog
    id2   dog     the cat jumps over the lazy dog
    id1   dolor   lorem ipsum dolor dog
    id3   write   i have no clue what to write
```